# Google Maps iOS myLocation

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, gps

I'm struggling with Google Maps' myLocation property, I always get nil, and can't figure out why. In my ViewDidLoad i set the following

```
map.myLocationEnabled = true
```

And in the function which gets called when the user wants to get his/her location, I run this:

```
print(map.myLocation)
```

I get that the first time it might got no location, but shouldn't I get a location after a while?

Answer (score 1):

I thought the same thing as well but you actually need to get the user's location first through Apple's `CLLocationManager` api. `import CoreLocation` and make your VC adhere to `CLLocationManagerDelegate` and use the `didUpdateLocations` method to get the user's current location then reflect it unto GMaps.

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps
import CoreLocation

class MapVC: UIViewController
{
    @IBOutlet weak var googleMap: GMSMapView!

    var locationManager: CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}

extension MapVC: CLLocationManagerDelegate
{
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus)
    {
        switch status
        {
        case .AuthorizedAlways:
            print("Location AuthorizedAlways")
            googleMap.myLocationEnabled = true
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        case .AuthorizedWhenInUse:
            print("Location AuthorizedWhenInUse")
            googleMap.myLocationEnabled = true
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        case .Denied:
            print("Location Denied")
            googleMap.myLocationEnabled = false
            locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

        case .NotDetermined:
            print("Location NotDetermined")
            googleMap.myLocationEnabled = false
            locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

        case .Restricted:
            print("Location Restricted")
            googleMap.myLocationEnabled = false
            locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
    {
        if locations.count > 0
        {
            googleMap.camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithTarget((locations.last?.coordinate)!, zoom: 10.0)
            googleMap.settings.myLocationButton = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, so it actually CLLocationsmanager that keep the map's myLocation updated? By just update every second? Is there a possibility for restricting how often it should update the location?

Comment: Yap..When called, the `didUpdateLocations` method triggers a request to the Apple servers requesting not only your current location but also different details regarding it like `postalCode`, `administrativeArea` etc. Now unless specified otherwise, the moment `locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()` is executed once, it will keep making requests to Apple's servers. At what rate? I have no idea as well. Your case I'd recommend creating a timer and setting its target to `locationManager` then executing the `startUpdatingLocaton` as its selector then stop updating inside the `didUpdateLocations`

Comment: So something like this:

`let timer = NSTimer()`; global variable for invalidation purposes.

`timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(60, target: self.locationManager, selector: #selector(self.startUpdatingLocation), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)`; this updates the user location every 60 seconds

Then add `locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()` in your `didUpdateLocations` method immediately after setting the GMaps camera stuff.

Since we are very careful developers and don't want timers hanging around, add 'timer.invalidate()' in your `viewWillDisappear` or `viewDidDisappear`